# Lipschitz function with an inductive sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function defined on the interval $[a,b]$ such that $0<a<b$:

$\forall x,y\in[a,b],x\neq y,|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|$ where $k>0$ .

1- Prove that the function $f$ is continuous.

2- We define an inductive sequence such that $x_0$ is give in $[a,b]$. and for every $n>0$:

$X_{n}=(\frac{1}{k}f(X_{n-1}))^{\frac{1}{3}}$. Prove that the sequence defined by $U_{n}=|X_{n}^{3}-s^{3}|$ converges to a real number $d\geq0$

**MY WORK**

**For number 1:**

I let $\epsilon>0$ and I let $\eta=\frac{\epsilon}{k}$ so by definition of uniform continuity:

$|x^{3}-y^{3}|<\eta\Rightarrow|f(x)-f(y)|<k|x^{3}-y^{3}|<k\eta=\epsilon$

So therefore $f$ is uniformly continuous. Is what I did correct?

**For number 2**

Using the Lipschitz function I got something like:

$|U_{n+1}-U_{n}|<k|U_{n}-U_{n-1}|$. I believe that I have to prove that this is a Cauchy sequence but I don't think it's possible because we just know that $k>0$.

Thank you for any help before hand.

Answer (score 0):

1) Let $g(x) = x^3$. Clearly $g$ is continuous and hence $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta > 0$ such that $\lvert g(y)-g(x) \rvert = \lvert y^3 - x^3 \rvert < \frac{\epsilon}{k} $ if $\lvert y-x \rvert <  \delta$. So,  $\lvert f(y) - f(x) \rvert < \epsilon$ if $\lvert y-x \rvert <  \delta$ and hence $f$ is continuous

2)$\lvert X_n^3 - X_{n-1}^3 \rvert = \lvert\frac{f(X_{n-1})-f(X_{n-2})}{k}\rvert < \lvert X_{n-1}^3 - X_{n-2}^3 \rvert$ and hence the sequence $(X_n^3)$ is cauchy and it converges to some $x$